# Способы создания и инициализации существующей базы для нового сайта при портировании ее на удаленный хостинг

Tags: mysql, веб-программирование, хостинг, инициализация

Допустим у меня есть написанный мною сайт который находится на локальном тестовом сервере моего компьютера. К нему подключена mysql база в которой таблицы созданы вручную через phpmyadmin. Пришло время залить этот сайт на домен. C файлами все понятно их заливают на файловую систему удаленного сервера через какой нибудь протокол (например ftp), а как быть с уже имеющимися базами? Я вижу три возможных варианта:

1. php скрипт написанный вручную с созданием базы, таблиц и наполнения их первоначальными данными (если требутся), который нужно запустить из браузера
2. заново создать все с помощью phpmyadmin на предоставленном хостинге
3. подключить локальную mysql к удаленной и выполнить некую магическую команду

Но это только мои размышления. Хотелось бы узнать как это сделать правильно.

Comment: 4. Освоить импорт/экспорт данных в phpMyAdmin и переносить данные двумя кликами мышки.

Comment: На локальном сервере через phpmyadmin экспортировать базу данных в файл, создать на удаленном сервере БД, открыть ее в серверном phpmyadmin и импортировать из файла

Comment: так просто! спасибо парни.